# How to connect a webserver

Tags: java, android, http

how to connect and retrive data from one webserver through coding in android  application?

How to achieve this ? Give me sample code for this

Answer (score 6):

One way is using [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/), and there are [examples from Apache](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/examples.html). Also see [this blog post](http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/) for an Android specific example.

Answer (score 0):

If the `java.net` package is available on Android, you can use the URL class.

```
import java.net.*;

...

URL url = new URL("http://example.com/whatever");
return (String) url.getContent();
```